# Character extraction from image

Tags: image, image-processing, cluster-analysis, k-means

Does anyone knows a good algorithm to extract characters from an image. All the characters are black and the background white. In fact, the images will be just a printed document. I'm thinking to use a search algorithm, such as DFS or BFS, to cluster the characters, but i'm not sure whether there is something better? Could you suggest libraries that might do the trick? I just want to cut the images to smaller images, each image representing a character.

Comment: use an OCR application, there are some open source ones too, here is [one](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this might be helpful but in the end I searched for the characters using DFS. I also had some heuristic to decide whether some pixel was part of the character or not.
Also, since some characters are separated (like i), later I had to decide whether to combine them.
It worked quite well in fact. It was done a lot of time ago, but decided to answer the question I asked a lot of time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Such algorithms are usually called OCR ( Optical Character Recognition ), under every operating system you may find ready to use utilities which do it better or worse, free, commercial, many of them. Actually, some are used e.g. with spam detection, for recognizing words on images in incoming email on-the-fly, so you can even do it from within shell, without even seeing images - more less successfully extract text from images to plain text files.

Comment: I already have an OCR application which works fine for one character at a time because the input is an image, which contains one character. I want to write a class to read an image, separate the characters in it to smaller images and input them in the ocr application.

Comment: I bet you can find some ocr APIs too.

Comment: This **definitely is a solved problem for OCR**, so use whatever the OCR applications use ... why would you insist to do it differently?

Answer (score 1):

In python through  `scipy` package you can use the `scipy.ndimage.label(img)` method .It should **label** the different characters in your image ,afterwards use the `scipy.ndimage.find_objects` to extract those characters.but you need to invert your image first so your background color is black not white.

You may want to post the image to see exactly what you want.